# I need to find minimum number in 2d array (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm very bad at assembly, so I've made something like this. The problem is that it doesn't work. Can you help me? I surfed the net and I've seen some code which find the number of the same elements. I've changed it a bit, but there is some error about `move_next`. 
My code:

```
 STACK 256
 .data
     array dw 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
     min dw 1
 .code
 main:
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds,ax
     xor ax,ax
     mov si,0
     mov bx,0
     mov cx,5
 external:
     mov ax,array[bx][si]
     push cx
     mov cx,5
     mov si,0
 iternal:
     inc si
     cmp ax,min
     jle here
     loop iternal
 here:
     jcxz move_next 
     mov min, ax
     move_next      <==================== This is your first error
     pop cx
     add bx,1
     loop external
 output:
     mov ax,min 
      pop dx
          add dl, 30h  
     int 21h       
     loop output  
         mov ah, 09h
         int 21h              
     exit: ;выход
     mov ax,4c00h 
     int 21h
     end main
```

Minimum

```
MODEL small
    STACK 256
    .data
    rows dw 4
    cols dw 5
        array dw 5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,11,12,13,14,15,16,0,18,19,20
        min dw 1
    newend db 0dh,0ah,'$'

    .code
putdigit macro  ;макрос виводу чисел массиву
    local lput1
    local lput2
    local exx

    push    ax
    push    cx
    push    -1  
    mov     cx,10   
lput1:  xor     dx,dx   
    mov     ah,0                   
    div     cl   
    mov     dl,ah   
    push    dx  
    cmp al,0    
    jne lput1   
    mov ah,2h
lput2:  pop dx  
    cmp dx,-1    
    je  exx
    add dl,'0'  
    int 21h 
    jmp lput2   
exx:
    mov dl,' ' 
    int 21h
    pop cx
    pop     ax
endm

    main:
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        xor ax,ax
        mov si,0
        mov cx,40
    find:
        mov ax,array [si]
    add si, 2
        cmp ax, min
    jge not_less     
        mov min, ax
    not_less: 
    loop find  
output:
    lea bx,array
    mov cx,rows 
out1:
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,newend
    int 21h
    push cx
    mov cx, cols
    mov si, 0

out2:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ax,[si][bx]
    putdigit
    add si, 2
    loop out2

    add bx, cols
    pop cx
    loop out1 

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,newend
    int 21h




    mov ax,min
    putdigit
    exit: 
     mov ax,4c00h 
     int 21h
     end main
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem, where you are stuck in more detail? What kind of error do you receive? What is the error message?

Comment: I`ve an error message"Undefined symbol MOVE_NEXT". I don`t know what is a problem.

Comment: It's telling you the problem. `move_next` isn't recognized as a symbol. Try adding a colon on the line where you define `move_next`.

Comment: how should i do this?

Comment: The `move_next` label is defined, the next label after the `here` label. Is that still the error?

Comment: yes,the same problem

Comment: Are you building the *first* fragment, or the *second* one? The first fragment indeed has no `move_next` label, instead it's written without a colon, as a command. Do you understand the difference between commands and labels? See the question edit.

Comment: I understand now, there is no error, but the code doesn't work. Can you help me to fix it (I need to find minimum number in the 2d array)?

Comment: i can write it using the c++. It'a part of homework (the other one is to use macros), but I just want to understand how to do this, I don't care about mark. Can you help me to understand how to do it?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: In NASM at least, a token on a line by itself is treated as a label if it's not recognized as a mnemonic or directive.  So `move_next` is equivalent to `move_next:`.  Indenting it that way and omitting the `:` is extremely bad style and super confusing for human readers, but that's why it can still assemble.   NASM warns `warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]`.  It looks like this is MASM or TASM, though; IDK what they'll do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, there will be no complete code. Some pointers instead.

So you are looking for a minimum in a 2D array. The sample you've found performs a nested loop. **Strictly speaking, this is not necessary** unless you are looking for **the index** of the minimal element. Since the array is contiguous in memory, you can scan the whole array in one loop and output the minimum you find. In your case, that means initializing `CX` to 20 initially, and no internal loop.

Now, about the logic of scanning the array. It's similar to what you would have in C++ - get the next element, compare to the running minimum, if the element is smaller than the minimum, assign the element value to the minimum. Assembly adds some flavor to that.

In a C++ function, you'd have an index variable that goes from 0 to (array size-1). Same here, except you need to account for the fact that the array contains two byte words (declared as `DW`).

To recap:

- initialize the registers
- loop for 20 iterations
- running index in SI
- load the current element into AX
- compare AX to the running minimum
- if less, assign AX to the running minimum
- increase the index
- continue the loop
- output and exit

Can you do that? Which part are you not sure about

---

About comparison. This is one of those things that are different in assembly, compared to high level languages like C++. The CPU has a `FLAGS` register, which changes its value based on the result of the last arithmetic operation. You can then perform conditional jumps based on the individual flag values. There's no `if/else` statement *per se* in x86 assembly, only conditional jumps.

Specifically, when you want to do `if(ax < min)min=ax`, in assembly it would be go something like that:

```
    cmp ax, min      //Compare ax to min - the FLAGS are set
    jge not_less     //If ax >= min, jump to the not_less label.
                     //"ge" stands for "greater or equal"
    mov min, ax      //Else (that is, if ax < min), assign ax to min
not_less:            //This is the label
```

---

About the latest edit.

First, you have the "output the number" logic twice - once in `putdigit`, once again in the portion where you output the min. Just reuse the `putdigit` for the latter; it prints the value of AX. Load `min` into AX and call `putdigit`.

Now, about your print the array loop. Your `add bx, cols` line is off; you want to shift the value of BX by the row size *in memory*, which is not 5 but 10, because you have an array of two byte words. Also, even though the numbers are small and fit in one byte, it's incorrect to load the high byte; instead of `mov al,[si][bx]`, do `mov ax,[si][bx]`. Since your assembler seems to be properly scaling SI by the array size, instead of `adc si, 2` restore `inc si`. The `ADC` command is pointless here.

You have two `int 21h` lines in a row. The first one outputs a newline, the other one is pointless. Remove it.

There are numerous other issues with the code, but let's get those two out of the way first.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214297/discussion-on-answer-by-seva-alekseyev-i-need-to-find-minimum-number-in-2d-array).